# Compiling less with webpack

Tags: less, webpack

I want to add a very basic less file to my [project](https://github.com/pbrianmackey/uiexperiment) on github (see [this commit](https://github.com/pbrianmackey/uiexperiment/commit/71cce2b73a387ca5019bc600ca55a2c24f5093b8)).

#### style.less

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less']
}
```

#### Command line build command

```sh
webpack --config webpack.config.js -d
```

#### Index.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.less" />
```

I expected the deployment folder to now contain bundle.css which contains the contents of my less file.  This did not happen.

How do I setup webpack to compile my less?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of things needed to be [corrected](https://github.com/pbrianmackey/uiexperiment/commit/1860d89f858fe9cb63f76cfcf33316c7e389b32b):

1. Add `require('./myPath/myFile.less')` to your `app.js` (or entry point).

   The less file does not go in the index.html file.
2. You need a few dependencies.  The versions I used are:

   ```
   "less": "^2.7.1",
   "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
   "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
   "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
   ```

Comment: Re: #1 
I am amazed this detail isn't in the docs. StackOverflow saves the day again.

For those using typescript:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064890/how-to-require-import-less-file-in-typescript-file