# less css not rendering (for a split second) on page load

Tags: css, less

I'm using less css in my stylesheets. I'm also in localhost via xampp.
I'm having an issue with my stylesheet not rendering (for a split second) on page load.
The page loads quickly without the styles, then loads just a split second later with the styles applied.

Has anyone had any similar issues using less?

**header.php**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Feed</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- style sheets -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.8.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-design-blocks/2.0.1/css/froala_blocks.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="styles.less" />
      <!-- scripts -->
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" ></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
    </head>
      <body style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require 'navbar/navbar.php';
    require 'header.php';
?>

<!-- My HTML source here -->
```

**styles.less**

```
@import 'whitetheme.variables.less';

/* styles are here */
```

**whitetheme.variables.less**

```
    @dark-font-color: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
    @medium-font-color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    @light-font-color: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    @secondary-background: #fff;
    @primary-gray: #f0f2f5;
    @primary-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    @primary-blue: #4c8bf5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

instead of

```
<?php
    require 'navbar/navbar.php';
    require 'header.php';
?>
```

I just needed to require my header first

```
<?php
    require 'header.php';
    require 'navbar/navbar.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> less css not rendering (for a split second) on page load

- LESS is not CSS.
- Browsers do not natively support using LESS files (`*.less`) as stylesheets.
- LESS is a system that generates CSS stylesheet files for you.

  - LESS is intended to be used as part of a *build process* (which you'd automate with `npm run`, or Gulp, or WebPack, or Rollup, or whatever the JavaScript ecosystem thinks is cool this month).
- You are using an external third-party script to convert LESS to CSS *in the browser*, which is the cause of the delay.

Specifically, here's your problem:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="styles.less" />
> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" ></script>
> ```

You're using a LESS processor script *that runs in the browser* to convert your `.less` file into a CSS stylesheet that browsers can natively understand - this process happens asynchronously and independently of the browser loading the page.

This is what's happening (in chronological order, as your browser loads the page):

1. The browser loads your `/` page (that's the HTML output of your `index.php` script).
2. The browser loads `styles.less` asynchronously.

   - However, browsers will load `rel="stylesheet"` resources synchronously and block the page render, however.
3. The browser loads `less.min.js` synchronously (as you aren't using the `defer` or `async` attributes) and it then runs and processes your LESS and converts it to CSS.

   - The `less.min.js` file *will wait* until `less.min.js` is loaded, however.
4. And it's during that wait-for-`less.min.js`-file period that the browser renders your page (fast, isn't it?) *without* the CSS styles that it doesn't have yet.

The best fix is to run the LESS-to-CSS conversion step as part of a *project build process*. I suggest you read-up on `npm` and the rest in order to do this properly.

---

Something like this:

[Compiling less with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133323/compiling-less-with-webpack)

1. Install Webpack and LESS:

   - https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-loader
   - https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

   ```
   cd your-project
   npm init -y
   npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
   npm install less less-loader --save-dev
   ```
2. Configure Webpack + LESS:

   **webpack.config.js**:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.less$/i,
           loader: [
             // compiles Less to CSS
             "style-loader",
             "css-loader",
             "less-loader",
           ],
         },
       ],
     },
   };
   ```
3. Run `npx webpack`
4. Edit your HTML:

   - Remove the `<script>` to `less.min.js`.
   - Update the `<link>` to point to the output `.css` file from Step 3.